# How to use flask_sqlalchemy to connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

How to use flask_sqlalchemy to connect to mysql and with username and password

I used sqlite but I am not able to set username and password.

What I tried
DB_PRODUCT_PATH = "mysql://admin:passowrd@localhost:3306/mydb"

Is this correct?

If I use sqlite, how can I set password for sqlite

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks I need add mysqlconnector, mysql+mysqlconnector:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).